# Android adjustViewBounds Inside wrap_content Bug?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TextView and an ImageButton inside LinearLayout. I want the height of the Button equal to TextViews height. And adjust its width to preserve image ratio. It works fine if I set LinearLayout's height manually(equal to TextView's height). But if I use wrap_content to set LinearLayout height, for somewhat reason ImageButtons width shrinks. How can I get around this?

[image: Button is ok]

[image: When the button shrinks]

Comment: ImageButton- `height`=`match_parent`, `width`=`wrap_content`

Comment: Yes I already use these values. It works as expected in the first picture. But when I set layout_height: wrap_content on LinearLayout, the button gets shrinked.